# How to setup a multilingual site with the same domain but different home items

Tags: sxa, multisite

I have a single SXA site with multiple language versions like English,German,French,Italian etc.

Now, I have following requirement :

Each language version must have it's own content node like below with same set of pages inside them with EN-Home will have only English language, DE-Home with only German language and so on.

[image]

Now my url must look like

1. [www.mydomain.com/en-us](http://www.mydomain.com/en-us)
2. [www.mydomain.com/de-de](http://www.mydomain.com/de-de)
3. [www.mydomain.com/fr-fr](http://www.mydomain.com/fr-fr)

I tried adding Site Groupings like below(by selecting respective content node with language) but it does not resolve properly.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to make this work would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you are calling it Multilingual sites, they are setup as multisite since you have different Home Nodes for each language. (I would suggest you to not to alter SXA's native site Site structure to add multiple Home nodes.)

You can create multiple sites instead. Like -

- Public Site DE > Home
- Public Site FR > Home
- Public Site EN > Home

And for each site, create a site definition item.

All site definitions can have same host name but with different virtual folder and language.

For Public Site DE, Site definition item will have -

- Host Name : [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)
- Virtual folder : de-de
- Language : de-DE

This should work the way you need.

**Ideally**, you should not have 3 Home nodes if you want to implement multilingual site.

- You should create just 1 Home node instead.
- Add languages [Enabling Multilingual Support with SXA](https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/06/03/enabling-multilingual-support-with-sxa/)
- Create all necessary language versions of your items as I see same
  items under each language Home Node
- Make use of *Language Embedding* attribute in Site Definition item. In your case, you can set it to *Always* [Site Definition in SXA](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-sxa-site-definition-fields.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. We had already tried this solution. But I didn't add correct language code in virtual folder . I added /de-de instead of /de-DE.

 So I would ask anyone who tries this solution, to keep this point in mind